# How can I fit an image to whole screen in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, imshow

I am wondering how I can fit an image to the whole screen in Matlab.

I have a small patch of uniform color in the middle (e.g. Blue), and would like make the whole screen become Blue. In the other words, I want to remove all borders and toolbars and so on.

Thank you for any help

Comment: I applied many of those answers and didn't work.

Comment: This is the proposed solution in this site: figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])
This is not the answer of my Q. I need the "whole" screen becomes blue (e.g)

Comment: There is only **one** answer on the link I marked as duplicate.  You obviously didn't bother to read it.  Also, what you suggested is **not** the proposed answer that I linked to.  Leaving as closed.